# Copy/Move files from SharePoint custom list attachment into Amazon cloud server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, development, designer-workflow

I'm a guest to the site and after seeing the great quality of Q&A's, I would like to ask anyone if you can able to assist me with this problem.

Brief background:

- I have Admin/Full Control of a collection of sub-sites and root site.
- I've been working with SP workflows, adding basic logic to a custom list
  field using InfoPath but never had developed/adding in-line
  programming codes into our SharePoint site.

Current setup:

We have a custom list in which fields are to be filled-up by the users, along with the attachment file that needs to be reviewed and a "Deploy" button. After the files has been reviewed by the administrator, the administrator will then click the "deploy" button, to move/copy the attachment file into a shared folder of our Amazon server.

Problem:

How can we copy/move the attachment file from SP to the Amazon server while passing the same credentials used by the administrator?

Can I also achieve this by only using SP workflow in the SP Designer?

---

- I'm seeing that adding JavaScript into the custom list web part will do
  the trick, but I'm not really sure how to start or write my code.
- If there are other alternatives, is it okay if I can get some guides
  in order to solve this problem?

Any help is very much appreciated.